# Dynamic Json File Value Update

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to dynamically change a JSON File.
ex, JSON:

```
{
  "name":"Andrew";
  "Date of Birth":"22-12-2000"
}
```

but instead of the value of Date of Birth in JSON file being hard coded, I want it to be current System date. ex.

```
{
  "name":"Andrew";
  "Date of Birth":var
}
```

How can this be done? Using variables in Java code to load the JSON data and make changes is not feasible. I wanted to know if its possible to dynamically change the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two functions that return the 'current' date/time timestamp:

```
1-$now() returns the timestamp in an ISO 8601 formatted string.
```

2-$millis() returns the same timestamp as the number of milliseconds since
midnight on 1st January 1970 UTC (the Unix epoch).

example:-

```
 {
 "invoiceTime": $now(),
 "total": $sum(Account.Order.Product.(Price * Quantity)),
 "closingTime": $now()
  }
```